# Error: Django Framework : NoReverseMatch at /accounts/create/ 'shop' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I seem to be getting the error mentioned in the title:

```
"NoReverseMatch at /accounts/create/
'shop' is not a registered namespace"
```

This is my base.html file which is saying is the route of the error:

> Error during template rendering
> In template C:\Users\conor\djangoprojects\sem4proh01march\phoneshop\templates\base.html, error at line 24
> 'shop' is not a registered namespace

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
    <meta name="description" content="{% block metadescription %}{% endblock %}">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {% include 'header.html' %}
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% include 'footer.html' %}
    </div>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your urls.py file and the template giving this error. `/accounts/create/` does not seem to be mentioned in the given code. It can be one of included templates.

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding something like this in your global urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
     ...
     ...
     path("shop/", include("your_app_name.shop.urls", namespace="shop")),
     ...
]
```